# Insert table in footer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I want to add footer to my master page in sharepoint 2013 and I follow the steps in https://www.eliostruyf.com/sticky-footer-solution-for-sharepoint-2013/ but I do not want this to be just a line I want to put information in this but when I just insert my code which created in a SharePoint page

```
<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="ms-rteTable-0">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-0">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" style="width: 25%;">​ 
            <div class="footer_Sectionheader" style="font-family: wmitrar; font-weight: bold; color: #999999; padding-right: 20px; border-bottom: 2px solid #333333; background-color: transparent;">فاوا<br/></div>
            <div class="footer_TextContent" style="font-family: &quot;b koodak&quot;; font-size: 12px; color: #999999; padding-right: 10px; background-color: #444444;">
               <ul style="margin-right: -20px;">
                  <li>
                     <a href="/ict/Lists/SpamEmailList/Item/newifs.aspx?List=974e6025-a879-4f4e-8f7e-7c71c769205c&amp;RootFolder=&amp;Web=9267227d-feff-415a-99a7-ce659ae2dd6e" style="color: #999999;">اعلام ایمیل اسپم</a><br/></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="/ict/ICTSvcCtg/_layouts/VisioWebAccess/VisioWebAccess.aspx?listguid=%7bBA73D52B-B676-4B1C-A0D5-EDDC4F9C23DF%7d&amp;itemid=2&amp;DefaultItemOpen=1" style="color: #999999;">خدمات فاوا</a><br/></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="/DocLib2/Forms/AllItems.aspx" style="color: #999999;">کتابخانه الکترونیکی</a><br/></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer_Sectionheader" style="font-family: wmitrar; font-weight: bold; color: #999999; padding-right: 20px; border-bottom: 2px solid #333333; background-color: transparent;">مرکز اسناد پروژه<br/></div>
            <div class="footer_TextContent" style="font-family: &quot;b koodak&quot;; font-size: 12px; color: #999999; padding-right: 10px; background-color: #444444;">
               <ul style="margin-right: -20px;">
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://portal:30165/sites/ngL3100/" style="color: #999999;">پروژه NGL3100</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://portal:30165/sites/SP2021other" style="color: #999999;">پروژه 20 و 21 پارس جنوبی</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://portal:30165/sites/1718site" style="color: #999999;">پروژه 17 و 18 پارس جنوبی</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://portal:30165/dmc/NGLsiri" style="color: #999999;">پروژه NGL Siri</a><br/></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <br/>
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-0" style="width: 25%;">​ 
            <div class="footer_Sectionheader" style="font-family: wmitrar; font-weight: bold; color: #999999; padding-right: 20px; border-bottom: 2px solid #333333; background-color: transparent;">پیوندها<br/></div>
            <div class="footer_TextContent" style="font-family: &quot;b koodak&quot;; font-size: 12px; color: #999999; padding-right: 10px; background-color: #444444;">
               <ul style="margin-right: -20px;">
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.eni.com/it_IT/home.html" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">آژانس بین المللی انرژی</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.opec.org/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">اوپک</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.mop.ir/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">وزارت نفت</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.nipc.net/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">شرکت ملی صنایع پتروشیمی</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.pogc.ir/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">شرکت نفت و گاز پارس</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.oiec-gcc.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">تعاونی اعتبار</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="https://ebanking.bankmellat.ir/ebanking/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">بانکداری الکترونیکی بانک ملت</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://tanzil.net/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">تنزیل قرآن</a><br/></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <br/>
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" style="width: 25%;">​
            <div class="footer_Sectionheader" style="font-family: wmitrar; font-weight: bold; color: #999999; padding-right: 20px; border-bottom: 2px solid #333333; background-color: transparent;">خبرگزاری ها<br/></div>
            <div class="footer_TextContent" style="font-family: &quot;b koodak&quot;; font-size: 12px; color: #999999; padding-right: 10px; background-color: #444444;">
               <ul style="margin-right: -20px;">
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.hamshahrionline.ir/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">روزنامه همشهری</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://jamejamonline.ir/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">روزنامه جام جم</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.shana.ir/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">شانا</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.irna.ir/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">ایرنا</a><br/></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.ogj.com/" target="_blank" class="en" style="font-family: tahoma; color: #999999;">Oil &amp; Gas Journal</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.worldoil.com/" target="_blank" class="en" style="font-family: tahoma; color: #999999;">World Oil</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.ft.com/companies/oil-gas" target="_blank" class="en" style="font-family: tahoma; color: #999999;">Oil &amp; gas companies news</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="http://www.rigzone.com/news/" target="_blank" class="en" style="font-family: tahoma; color: #999999;">Rigzone</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="https://www.oilandgaspeople.com/news/" target="_blank" class="en" style="font-family: tahoma; color: #999999;">Oil and Gas People</a><br/></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <br/>
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-0" style="width: 25%;">​ 
            <div class="footer_Sectionheader" style="font-family: wmitrar; font-weight: bold; color: #999999; padding-right: 20px; border-bottom: 2px solid #333333; background-color: transparent;">برنامه های سازمانی<br/></div>
            <div class="footer_QuickLinks" style="width: 217px; color: #000000; font-family: wmitrar; font-size: medium;">
               <a href="http://papp/OICT/List/TotalRequest.aspx?Sys_Id=OICT&amp;Mdl_Id=OICT004&amp;Project_Id=OIEC" style="color: #004085;">
                  <div class="footer_QLink Link1" style="background-color: #c7b05e; width: 66px; height: 66px; float: left; margin: 5px 1px 1px; text-align: center; color: white;">
                     <img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/Support.png" alt="Support" style="width: 48px; display: block; margin: 5px;"/>
                     <span class="en" style="font-family: tahoma; bottom: 14px; font-size: 12px;">Helpdesk</span></div></a><a href="http://papp/ORMS/Default.aspx?Sys_Id=ORMS&amp;Project_Id=OIEC" style="color: #004085;">
                  <div class="footer_QLink Link2" style="background-color: #88aebe; width: 66px; height: 66px; float: left; margin: 5px 1px 1px; text-align: center; color: white;">
                     <img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/Food.png" alt="Food" style="width: 48px; display: block; margin: 5px;"/>
                     <span style="bottom: 14px; font-size: 12px;">رستوران</span></div></a><a href="http://oiecinout/LoginForms/Login.aspx" style="color: #004085;">
                  <div class="footer_QLink Link3" style="background-color: #b9513e; width: 66px; height: 66px; float: left; margin: 5px 1px 1px; text-align: center; color: white;">
                     <img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/Transport.png" alt="Transport" style="width: 48px; display: block; margin: 5px;"/>
                     <span style="bottom: 14px; font-size: 12px;">تردد</span></div></a><a href="http://oiecwf/Login.aspx?PG=/default.aspx" style="color: #004085;">
                  <div class="footer_QLink Link4" style="background-color: #cc2a86; width: 66px; height: 66px; float: left; margin: 5px 1px 1px; text-align: center; color: white;">
                     <img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/Works.png" alt="Works" style="width: 48px; display: block; margin: 5px;"/>
                     <span style="bottom: 14px; font-size: 12px;">گردش کار</span></div></a><a href="http://payslip/" style="color: #004085;">
                  <div class="footer_QLink Link5" style="background-color: #bf56bc; width: 66px; height: 66px; float: left; margin: 5px 1px 1px; text-align: center; color: white;">
                     <img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/Salary.png" alt="Salary" style="width: 48px; display: block; margin: 5px;"/>
                     <span style="bottom: 14px; font-size: 12px;">حقوق</span></div></a><a href="https://mail.oiecgroup.com/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&amp;url=https://mail.oiecgroup.com/owa/" style="color: #004085;">
                  <div class="footer_QLink Link6" style="background-color: #5f7978; width: 66px; height: 66px; float: left; margin: 5px 1px 1px; text-align: center; color: white;">
                     <img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/Email.png" alt="Email" style="width: 48px; display: block; margin: 5px;"/>
                     <span style="bottom: 14px; font-size: 12px;">پست الکترونیکی</span></div></a><a href="/Lists/PersonnelPhonNumber" style="color: #004085;">
                  <div class="footer_QLink Link7" style="background-color: #90c46c; width: 66px; height: 66px; float: left; margin: 5px 1px 1px; text-align: center; color: white;">
                     <img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/Telephones.png" alt="Telephones" style="width: 48px; display: block; margin: 5px;"/>
                     <span style="bottom: 14px; font-size: 12px;">لیست تماس ها</span></div></a>
               <div class="footer_QLink Link8" style="color: white; background-color: #d9712b; width: 66px; height: 66px; float: left; margin: 5px 1px 1px; text-align: center;">
                  <img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/Forum.png" alt="Forum" style="width: 48px; display: block; margin: 5px;"/>
               </div>
               <div>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
               </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-0">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" colspan="4">​ ​ 
            <div class="footer_Sectionheader" style="font-family: wmitrar; font-weight: bold; color: #999999; padding-right: 20px; border-bottom: 2px solid #333333; background-color: transparent;">اطلاعات تماس<br/></div>
            <div class="footer_TextContent" style="font-family: &quot;b koodak&quot;; font-size: 12px; color: #999999; padding-right: 10px; background-color: transparent;">
               <div class="footer_boxed" style="float: right; display: inline-block; width: 217px; height: 87px; font-family: wmitrar;">
                  <div class="footer_contactinfo" style="float: right; height: 80px; width: 880px; margin: 2px 5px 5px; display: inline-block;"> 
                     <img class="footer_boxedimg" src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/logo/oiec.png" alt="" style="float: right; width: 80px; margin: 5px; display: inline-block; background-color: #eeeeee; border-radius: 5px; height: 80px;"/> 
                     <div class="footer_contactinfo_Item" style="float: right; padding: 2px; display: inline-block; width: 220px; height: 25px; top: 5px;"> 
                        <span class="footer_TextTitle" style="font-weight: bold; color: #aaaaaa; padding-right: 10px;"><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/location.png" width="16" alt="Address" style="margin: 5px;"/>آدرس:&#160;</span>تهران، کامرانیه جنوبی، کوچه پیروز، شماره 2</div>
                     <div class="footer_contactinfo_Item" style="float: right; padding: 2px; display: inline-block; width: 220px; height: 25px; top: 5px;"> 
                        <span class="footer_TextTitle" style="font-weight: bold; color: #aaaaaa; padding-right: 10px;"><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/po.png" width="16" alt="P.O." style="margin: 5px;"/>کد پستی:&#160;</span>1958543811</div>
                     <div class="footer_contactinfo_Item" style="float: right; padding: 2px; display: inline-block; width: 220px; height: 25px; top: 5px;"> 
                        <span class="footer_TextTitle" style="font-weight: bold; color: #aaaaaa; padding-right: 10px;"><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/fax.png" width="16" alt="Fax" style="margin: 5px;"/>فکس:&#160;</span>22215851</div>
                     <div class="footer_contactinfo_Item" style="float: right; padding: 2px; display: inline-block; width: 220px; height: 25px; top: 5px;"> 
                        <span class="footer_TextTitle" style="font-weight: bold; color: #aaaaaa; padding-right: 10px;"><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/phone.png" width="16" alt="Phone" style="margin: 5px;"/>تلفن:&#160;</span>22218005<br/></div>
                     <div class="footer_contactinfo_Item" style="float: right; padding: 2px; display: inline-block; width: 220px; height: 25px; top: 5px;"> 
                        <span class="footer_TextTitle" style="font-weight: bold; color: #aaaaaa; padding-right: 10px;"><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/email.png" width="16" alt="email" style="margin: 5px;"/>ایمیل:</span>&#160;<span class="en" style="font-family: tahoma;">info@oiecgroup.com</span></div>
                     <div class="footer_contactinfo_Item" style="float: right; padding: 2px; display: inline-block; width: 220px; height: 25px; top: 5px;"> 
                        <span class="footer_TextTitle" style="font-weight: bold; color: #aaaaaa; padding-right: 10px;"><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/www.png" width="16" alt="www" style="margin: 5px;"/>سایت:</span><a href="http://www.oiecgroup.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;"><span class="en" style="font-family: tahoma;">www.oiecgroup.com</span></a><br/></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div> 
            <br/> ​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-0">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" colspan="4">​ 
            <div class="footer_Sectionheader" style="font-family: wmitrar; font-weight: bold; color: #999999; padding-right: 20px; border-bottom: 2px solid #333333; background-color: transparent;">شرکتهای تابعه<br/></div>
            <div class="footer_rowboxed" style="width: 890px; height: 95px; margin: 2px; color: #000000; font-family: wmitrar; font-size: medium; background-color: #444444;">
               <div class="footer_boxed" style="float: right; display: inline-block; width: 217px; height: 95px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999;">
                  <span class="footer_boxedheader en" style="font-family: tahoma; float: right; height: 20px; width: 120px; margin: 5px 0px 0px; padding-right: 4px; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;"> 
                     <a href="http://www.eied.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">EIED</a></span><span class="footer_boxeddesc" style="float: right; width: 800px; margin: 0px; display: inline-block; direction: rtl;"><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/location.png" width="16" alt="Address" style="margin: 5px;"/>آدرس: پاسداران، کوهستان دوم، شماره 4<br/><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/phone.png" width="16" alt="Phone" style="margin: 5px;"/>تلفن: 22565040<br/><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/fax.png" width="16" alt="Fax" style="margin: 5px;"/>فکس: 22544327</span></div>
               <div class="footer_boxed" style="float: right; display: inline-block; width: 217px; height: 95px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999;">
                  <span class="footer_boxedheader en" style="font-family: tahoma; float: right; height: 20px; width: 120px; margin: 5px 0px 0px; padding-right: 4px; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;"> 
                     <a href="http://www.oeid.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">OEID</a></span><span class="footer_boxeddesc" style="float: right; width: 800px; margin: 0px; display: inline-block; direction: rtl;"><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/location.png" width="16" alt="Address" style="margin: 5px;"/>آدرس: تهران، بلوار نلسون ماندلا، بلوار صبا، پلاک 20<br/><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/phone.png" width="16" alt="Phone" style="margin: 5px;"/>تلفن: 40-22019736<br/><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/fax.png" width="16" alt="Fax" style="margin: 5px;"/>فکس: 22020773</span></div>
               <div class="footer_boxed" style="float: right; display: inline-block; width: 217px; height: 95px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999;">
                  <span class="footer_boxedheader en" style="font-family: tahoma; float: right; height: 20px; width: 120px; margin: 5px 0px 0px; padding-right: 4px; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;"> 
                     <a href="http://www.oico.ir/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">OICO</a></span><span class="footer_boxeddesc" style="float: right; width: 800px; margin: 0px; display: inline-block; direction: rtl;"><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/location.png" width="16" alt="Address" style="margin: 5px;"/>آدرس: تهران، خیابان نلسون ماندلا (آفریقا)، بعد از<br/>میرداماد، خیابان قبادیان شرقی، پلاک 11<br/><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/phone.png" width="16" alt="Phone" style="margin: 5px;"/>تلفن: 96623636&#160;<br/><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/fax.png" width="16" alt="Fax" style="margin: 5px;"/>فکس: 96623636</span></div>
               <div class="footer_boxed" style="float: right; display: inline-block; width: 217px; height: 95px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999;">
                  <span class="footer_boxedheader en" style="font-family: tahoma; float: right; height: 20px; width: 120px; margin: 5px 0px 0px; padding-right: 4px; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;"> 
                     <a href="http://www.kpe.ir/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">KPE</a></span><span class="footer_boxeddesc" style="float: right; width: 800px; margin: 0px; display: inline-block; direction: rtl;"><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/location.png" alt="Address" style="margin: 5px;"/>آدرس: تهران، پاسداران، کوهستان ششم، شماره 12<br/><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/phone.png" width="16" alt="Phone" style="margin: 5px;"/>تلفن: 27620<br/><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/fax.png" width="16" alt="Fax" style="margin: 5px;"/>فکس: 26114650</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer_rowboxed" style="width: 890px; height: 95px; margin: 2px; color: #000000; font-family: wmitrar; font-size: medium; background-color: #444444;">
               <div class="footer_boxed" style="float: right; display: inline-block; width: 217px; height: 95px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999;">
                  <span class="footer_boxedheader en" style="font-family: tahoma; float: right; height: 20px; width: 120px; margin: 5px 0px 0px; padding-right: 4px; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;"> 
                     <a href="http://www.pogdcq.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #999999;">POGD</a></span><span class="footer_boxeddesc" style="float: right; width: 800px; margin: 0px; display: inline-block; direction: rtl;"><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/location.png" width="16" alt="Address" style="margin: 5px;"/>آدرس: تهران، طالقانی، نرسیده به چهارراه مفتح، شماره 234<br/><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/phone.png" width="16" alt="Phone" style="margin: 5px;"/>تلفن: 70-88318360<br/><img src="/SitePages/SamixTheme/Images/icon/fax.png" width="16" alt="Fax" style="margin: 5px;"/>فکس: 88303206</span></div>
               <div class="footer_boxed" style="float: right; display: inline-block; width: 217px; height: 95px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999;">&#160;<br/></div>
            </div>
            <br/> ​ ​ ​<br/></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<p>
</p>
```

instead of line  **This is my SharePoint 2013 Footer**, it does not work 
what should I do?

Comment: Are you using a custom Master Page? Also do you want to display your footer on SharePoint default pages?

Comment: yes I  customize the master page yes I  want footer in every pages